# How could i change form size (label,button in form also change...) in order to compatible with window size?

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to make a form and i don't know how to change form size .
[link](https://gyazo.com/b58aa04dfe923a98dd465d6b75d27333)

Comment: Open form in design mode and resize the form using size handlers or `Size` property of form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this code

```
Form1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
```

Comment: Form1 - the id/name of your winForm

Comment: Name : Form1 . I set default not change name

Comment: Do you want to calculate the size of the form based on the screen of the PC ?